# Turn all Actuators on Spring Boot 2.0 M6

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

I am unable to turn on all actuator endpoints on with a single configuration change. In my yaml configs I have tried the following:

```
endpoints:
  default:
    enabled: true
```

or

```
management:
  endpoints:
    default:
      enabled: true
    web:
      expose: "*"
      basePath: "/"
```

Turning them on individually works:

```
endpoints:
  beans:
    enabled: true
```

So that is a workaround, but I want to expose them all. The basePath parameter is working for me, but the web exposed is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Updated

#### Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6

For Spring Boot **2.0.0.M6**, `management.endpoints.web.expose` didn't exist. Please refer to class `WebEndpointProperties.java`.

By default, the following actuator endpoints are exposed:

- `application/status`
- `application/info`

To expose other actuator endpoints, you have to enable each endpoint property individually. Here is an example,

```
endpoints:
  health:
    enabled: true
  beans:
    enabled: true
  auditevents:
    enabled: true
  configprops:
    enabled: true
```

#### Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7

The property `management.endpoints.web.expose` came into existence in Spring Boot **2.0.0.M7**. It's used for exposing all actuator endpoints.

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      expose: "*"
```

[Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide) is the documentation.

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo in the original question. I have the correct yaml format. Still not seeing the endpoints.

Comment: Updated my posting.